# Kinetic js rotate to mouse with stage click

Tags: rotation, mouse, kineticjs, stage

got a problem with firing the mouse position event. The Object are moving when I drag them but not when I click on stage. What should I do? (of course I am adding a stage and layer and stuff ;)  Thanks a lot in advance!

```
function rotateAlltoMouse(layer3) {

      for(var n = 0; n < layer3.getChildren().length; n++) {
      var shape = layer3.getChildren()[n];
      var stage = shape.getStage();
      var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();



      var xd =  shape.getPosition().x - mousePos.x;
      var yd =  shape.getPosition().y - mousePos.y ;
       var theta = Math.atan2(yd, xd);
      var degree = theta / (Math.PI / 180) - 45;

      shape.setRotationDeg(degree);

    }
  }
     $('#container').bind('mousemove touchstart', function() {
                               rotateAlltoMouse(layer3);
                             });
```

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors? I dont think its safe to assume that all the children of a layer are shapes, since the first child is usually the `attrs` object that holds the attributes of the node. I would debug through your code carefully and ensure that each of your variables are what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a guess---could be better than a guess if you supply more code ;)**

Try requesting the containing DOM element with kineticJS so that you know you're getting the proper container.  KineticJS creates some supporting elements for its own use and your #container might not be getting the stage.

```
$(stage.getDOM()).on('mousemove',  function(){ rotateAlltoMouse(layer3); });
```